# How to have python audibly read text

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I just can't figure it out....I know how `python` can recognize my voice but I  don't know how to make `python` read text audibly.

```
from time import sleep
import sys
print("Tell me something...")
LOL = input()
sleep(2)
print("Thinking...")
sleep(2)
if LOL == 'Hey' or LOL == 'Hello':
    ???   #I want it to say Hello too!
else:
    print("ERROR")
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: What about this....http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578839-python-text-to-speech-with-pyttsx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are running under windows and you have pip installed, run `pip install speech` on a CMD window (run cmd with start menu and type cmd) after speech has installed stick `import speech` at the top of your python program. under your `if` statement put `speech.say('Hello!')`
Like this:

```
if LOL == 'Hey' or LOL == 'Hello':
    speech.say('Hello')
```

Comment: Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import speech
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\speech.py", line 157
    print prompt
               ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

Comment: What does this mean? I get it on my terminal

Comment: As it says, you have `Missing parentheses in call to 'print' `.

Comment: That looks like you are using IDLE, you need to go to your python script and follow the steps I detailed above :)

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have installed the speech library.

```
pip install speech
```

Then import it at the top of the python script

```
import speech
```

Then for what ever you want it to say, do:

```
speech.say("Text you want it to speak here")
```

For your case:

```
speech.say("Hello")
```

If that is not working for you, you can try installing pyTTSX package and looking for code snippets for it.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyttsx